# Drobo FS recognizing only 1 of my 5 3TB hard drives

Tags: drobo

so I have a Drobo FS [5 bay] and just updated everything to make sure I have the most recent firmware/dashboard software and am running into an issue.

I bought 5 3tb hitachi drives from http://www.ncix.com/products/?sku=59651&vpn=0S03230&manufacture=Hitachi for use in this unit. Put the first one in and it works fine, took a sec to format was then able to put files on it and have a blast. Went to put the second drive in and its saying there's a hard drive failure [note that in the drobo dashboard it is showing that it is a 3tb drive that has failed but still won't format it]

I tried this with all the remaining four drives and all had the same outcome. I also had a 1tb drive just sitting around the house so put that in to make sure it wasn't the drobo drive bay that was the issue but that one didn't have any issues and was formatted properly.

Is it possible I got 4 defective drives and 1 working one from ncix or is it possible that this is a drobo issue?

Comment: Why would you buy 5 *identical* drives when you want to keep your data safe?

Comment: They say that Drobo's predictive drive failure and consumer grade drives don't always play nice.

Comment: Did you try the drives in a computer first to make sure that they are actually good?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Drobo's are very picky with S.M.A.R.T. errors. I had to remove drives from a Drobo 2nd generation because some of the parameters were beyond Drobo's strict threshold. The drives work fine on my computer but Drobo won't accept them.